# How to open MFC application in regular window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

When I compile and run my program, I get window like this:

[image: Wrong]

But I want it to be in a window like this:

[image: Right]

Comment: I don't remember what the exact names are, but you have a few options for the window behavior when starting a project in VS. One of them is multi-document (your first picture) the other one is single-document (the second picture). There might be some others too, but you need to select the single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the File/New wizard again to create a simpler starting project. It looks like you selected the option to build a project with visual-studio-like appearance. Try selecting an SDI project with few or no extra options.

Comment: Thanks, but is there option to change one project from multi-document to SDI?

Comment: @wdc No there isn't, and you have a lot more stuff that you don't want in your project because it creates all those windows around the side. Try running through the File/New Project wizard several ways to get familiar with what you do and don't want for your project's starting point.